# check if an installed package is vulnerable to a given CVE number

Tags: vulnerability

Is there an "automatic/machine" way (meaning without manually checking in https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/) to check if an installed package (or given the installed package version) is vulnerable to a given CVE?